# Combine php with css

Tags: php, css

```
<style>
    #statusImages
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        top:50px;
        z-index:1;
    } 
</style>
```

I have a while loop and inside the while loop I want to change left  to the variable in the php code how can I do that

Comment: Are you trying to animate something? If so, you can't do it in PHP. You need either Javascript or different CSS and no while loop.

Comment: @MikeW lol and I see this comment after I post that answer.  Great minds I guess. +1

Comment: Why not switch a class in the html? I strongly suppose that this would be a much cleaner and better maintainable solution to your problem.

Comment: what Im trying to do is I'm querying stuff from a table and I display an image every time and for every image i want to move it a little so they won't overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your questions stands, your selector will select *one* element with the id of `statusImages`. Ids must be unique on the page, so if you have more than one image this won't work. You can use a class for most of the formatting, but because each element needs a different setting you'll have to add some inline styling too.

Add `style="left:???px"` to each element, something like this:

```
<style>
.statusImages   /* use a class selector here */
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  z-index:1;
}
</style>
<?php

$leftvalue = 100;
while (some condition) {
  echo "<img style='left:{$leftvalue}px' src='someimage.png' class='statusImages'>"
  $leftvalue += 20;
}
```

You'll need to adjust this to fit your own code.

Answer (score 0):

The style would have to be in a php file. Remember you can exit out of php at any time and just like in html it will just print what's there so you would be able to do something like this:

```
<style>
#statusImages
{
position:absolute;
left:<?php echo $leftValue ?>;
top:50px;
z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to have the `left` property continuously changed while this `while` loop supposedly runs, you're using the wrong side of the browser.

This has to be done client-side with Javascript.  What you get from a PHP file is already completed and will not change once it's on your desktop.

Comment: ok Yeah what Im trying to do is I'm querying stuff from a table and I display an image every time and for every image i want to move it a little so they won't overlap